# Minimize window on scroll down?

Tags: windows, window-managers, window-management

I was wondering, would it be possible to create a small piece of software **that would allow the user to minimize a window by scrolling down on it**? (on the top part that can be used to move it via drag and drop, obviously).

Following the same idea, it would be cool to be able to **scroll up on the task bar icons to restore a minimized windows**. I thought it would be cool (and since the user does not actually click but scrolls instead, it would prevent accidental nearby program openings when trying to restore a window)!

I am a total newbie when it comes to things like these. Could you please indicate me:

1. if Windows would let me do that (I doubt it wouldn't)?
2. How to code something like that (what language, and so on...)?

Comment: I've found [some starting points here](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=windows+window+manager+minimise+powershell). Powershell is just a suggestion, but I wonder if it is the easiest to get started with.

Comment: Thank you @halfer, I'll have a look at Powershell )

Answer (score 0):

A way of doing this for maximizing the tabs open in the taskbar would be to create a custom taskbar identical to that of the main one. The second taskbar from [Dual Monitor Taskbar](https://sourceforge.net/projects/dualmonitortb/) works this way. There are also libraries in languages such as **C++** which can detect scroll wheel movements.

Although this wasn't the most helpful answer, hopefully this could give you some ideas.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I'm personnaly not fan of the curstom taskbar, but I guess others may be! I'll look a bit more into what C++ has to offer, though )

Answer (score 0):

It is definitely possible. I found a software that does that  6 years ago and I have been using it ever since. It is called Preme for windows (http://www.premeforwindows.com/)

I have been using the software for about 6 years now and I cannot use windows without it. It also allows closing windows when clicking the mouse scroll key and maximizing a window with scroll up.

I hope this helps you. I am always wondering why Microsoft does have these options built in in the OS!!